# Ignoring/blocking/preventing 3XX redirects in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, redirection

How can I force my browser to IGNORE 3xx redirects? I want the browser to render the initial response, if any, and completely ignore any 3xx redirects. I need a convenient usable solution, ideally an extension with a website filter.

Answer (score 0):

settings > site settings > pop ups and redirects (near the bottom) > Don't allow sites to send pop-ups or use redirects (recommended)

No need for an extension

Comment: I asked specifically about HTTP 3xx redirects. This setting has nothing to do with these redirects and no control over them.